# For sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, why is $A\times B\times C$ is not the same as $(A\times B)\times C$.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have an intuitive sense as to why the associative law does not apply here, but can someone provide me with a more concrete reason as to why it doesn't? Thanks!

Comment: I have made an informed guess as to what you intended the title to be. Please correct or comment if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"?

Answer (score 1):

Fill in more details in: .... because $(1,2,3)$ has only one set of $()$ while $((1,2),3)$ has two sets of $()$. So they can't possibly be the same.

Answer (score -1):

For finite sets $A, B$ and $C$, since there exists a isomorphism between $A\times B\times C$ and $(A\times B)\times C$, probably the only difference is the notation. But things change when some of them are infinite.

Comment: Do you mean bijection? OP mentioned no algebraic structure on the sets.

Comment: Well, you could say an isomorphism in the category of sets is just a bijection.